# Turn Black Icons Grey in CSS?

Tags: css

Wondering how these guys at http://sociali.st turn their black icons grey in their CSS ("featured with love by" section).  New to this and can't figure it out.

Is their some property to allow me to change black icons to grey ones?

Comment: Did you inspect that???? the site is using opacity: 0.4

Comment: Sure did, but still can't figure it out.  Pretty new to this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do for your own like this:

```
div{
  background: url(path.jpg) no-repeat;
}
div:hover{
  opacity: .4;
}
```

And by the way that's good to do with black images.

But if you want to change colorful image to gray then you can use like this:

```
div:hover{
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
}
```

---

If you want to use opacity then see the [code](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/) for cross-browser compatibility:

```
 /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);

  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Good browsers */
  opacity: 0.5;
```

Answer (score 4):

They are using sprites for their black images with an opacity of .4. Upon :hover they remove the opacity restriction.  This is what the sprites look like at opacity 1:

[image]

Figured out by using firebug and inspecting the element.

Comment: I don't think your answer is correct.  I agree with MrChief.

Comment: They are not using sprites, simply changing Background color. See my answer.

Comment: Looks like a sprite to me...
http://sociali.st/wp-content/themes/socialist/library/css/../images/views/home/home-trust-logos.png?cache=251127031
Just showing that the original image is in fact black. Opacity is doing all the work.

Comment: That sprite doesn't contain the apple logo nor the button. Besides, check in firebug or Chrome dev tools. No sprites involved!

Comment: And where is the apple logo in the 'Featured with love by' section? The image I listed shows the sprites of all 'black' icons in the section requested by the original post.

Comment: In that section they are using the sprite and changing opacity. Just noticed it and I commented about the same to OP on my answer too.

Comment: I give credit where credit is due! +1! This is the second question today where I overlooked something. Maybe I should just rest today... :)

Answer (score 3):

They are using a [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) style to turn it into grey:

```
.button.button-app-store:hover {
   background: #262626;
   ...
```

The hover pseduo class is useful for highlighting a actionable element but it can also be used to create some nice tricks - such as cascading dropdown menus. It is commonly used on links and buttons to create this effect.

Using Chrome Developer tools, you can inspect that element and then simulate hover state like this:

[image]

which tells you how they achieve this effect.

Now if you uncheck the hover state, you can see that it falls back to the black color via this style:

```
.button.button-app-store {
   background: #171717;
   ...
```

Comment: Hmm... My Firefox is showing a different set of tabs on the right... Rules, Computed, Fonts, Box Model.

Comment: I'm using Chrome Dev tools, not Firebug. Or are you saying that a different site shows up in Firefox?

Comment: Right, got it.  I still find both Chrome Dev and Firebug to be a bit baffling, will have to study them more.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was talking about the icons further down the page.  Does that rule still apply?

Comment: Actually for the other icons, they are using a sprite and changing the opacity @aas4mis has pointed out.